# How to set albert shortcut key to just 'super'

Tags: albert

I want to trigger albert by just pressing the '`super`' key. But everytime I do so in albert's settings, it only shows '`meta + ?`' How do I make it happen?

Comment: Hello, in order to help you set the `Super` key to launch Albert. We need to know what distribution of Linux you have installed and what Desktop Environment you are running.

Comment: @iskyfire, I'm running Elementary OS 5.1.7 (I think it's based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) with their Panteon desktop environment.

Once elementary OS releases version 6 (based on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), I will switch to that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to rebind the super key in ElementaryOS by using the following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key "'Super_L'"
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior overlay-action "albert"
```

source: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2083

**Note:** You may have to use the command `albert toggle` instead.

Also, there was a comment in the answer that said:

> The shortcut worked...then I cannot use `super`+Num to switch any other workspaces. (I guess I just cannot use any combination with  as modifier)

**Meaning, this may or may not break other shortcuts that use the super key.**

I was able to reset changes I made to the `super` key bind in the **System Settings -> Keyboard** under **⌘ key behavior**. It will show as blank if it is modified, but you can choose from "Disabled", "Applications Menu", and "Shortcut Overlay". When I changed it to one of those settings, the keybind was overwritten and set so that it didn't open `albert` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately albert itself does not support modifier only hotkeys (meta, shift, ctrl, num). However, as @iskyfire said you can delegate the hotkey task to your desktop environment and let it call `albert toggle`.